# Why form.elements returns "object" elements?

Tags: html

"elements" attribute of a "form" element in HTML5 returns "object" elements.
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-listed

But I can't assume "object" elements as user-inputtable fields. Why "object"s are included?

Code example:

```
<form id="form1">
  <object id="foobar">
  </object>
</form>

var form = document.getElementById('form1');
var elements = form.elements;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   console.log(elements[i].id); // outputs "foobar"
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to be returned?

Comment: I expect it returns interactive controls or related. "button", "input", "keygen", "select", "textarea" elements represent interactive controls. "fieldset" is a container of controls. "output" is opposed to "input". I can't think "object" as a element related to interactive controls.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the snippet below clarifies things a little bit.

As you can see from running the code below, the element in this form is an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) as well as an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) and [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

Welcome to the wonderful world of inheritance.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var elements = form.elements;

for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
  var element = elements[i];

  console.log("Element with name: " + element.name);
  console.log("Element is Object: " + (element instanceof Object));
  console.log("Element is Element: " + (element instanceof Element));
  console.log("Element is HTMLElement: " + (element instanceof HTMLElement));
  console.log("Element is HTMLInputElement: " + (element instanceof HTMLInputElement));
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input name="text" type="text">
</form>
```